# Webform custom input mask

Tags: webforms

I'm trying to apply a custom input mask on a webform textfield
What I want is pretty similar to the built-in "Currency (+)" input mask, except I don't want the currency symbol.
However I can't figure out how to simply copy the currency input mask rule in order to modify it.
From the webform source code it seems that the regex used for this input mask is `^\$ [0-9]{1,3}(,[0-9]{3})*.\d\d$` but if I enter this value in the custom input mask field it simply doesn't work
I've also tried inputing `'regex': '[0-9]*'` in the custom input mask field and it works for simple regex like this one, but if I copy the currency one as `'regex': '^\$ [0-9]{1,3}(,[0-9]{3})*.\d\d$'` it doesn't (as if there wasn't any input mask entered).

I'm surprised the built-in input mask is hardcoded to use the $ sign and nobody seems to want to remove or use another symbol !

Could someone help me please ?
Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1):

When I select "currency" under Input Mask and then view the webform source, I see:

```
'#input_mask': '''alias'': ''currency'''
```

Currency is an alias provided by webform, which extends the 'numeric' alias provided by InputMask; see /js/webform.element.inputmask.js. If you want the Currency mask, but without the prefix $, then you can use this in the source:

```
currency: 
  '#type': textfield
  '#title': 'Currency'
  '#input_mask': '''alias'': ''currency'', ''prefix'': '''''
  '#required': true
```

Or, from the UI, select Custom under Input masks and add:

```
'alias': 'currency', 'prefix': ''
```

[image]

The key here is leveraging the alias "currency," but setting the prefix to empty. If you take a look at the webform javascript, you'll see other keys that can be overridden in the same way, for example, "placeholder" and "digits."

```
window.Inputmask.extendAliases({
  currency: {
    prefix: '$ ',
    groupSeparator: ',',
    alias: 'numeric',
    placeholder: '0',
    autoGroup: true,
    digits: 2,
    digitsOptional: false,
    clearMaskOnLostFocus: false
  },
```

You can learn more about extending InputMask aliases in the [InputMask documentation](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask).

Webform also provides some great examples in /modules/webform_examples/config/install/webform.webform.example_input_masks.yml.